# arduino nano with usb to ttl converter

Tags: arduino, usbserial

i have a usb to ttl converter and an arduino nano
the arduino nano's usb port stopped working for some reason, and hence i want to try using the usb to ttl converter to transfer sketches to the nano, how would I go about doing this??

i have tried connecting

```
Converter 5V > Arduino 5V (also tried VIN)
Converter GND > Arduino GND
Converter tx > Arduino Rx
Converter Rx > Arduino Tx
```

then used arduino nano on the arduino software and compiled and tried to upload, but it stayed on upload and did not move from upload, the rx and tx lights do not blink (sometimes the RX light turns on and stays on)

after a while i get this error

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

I have tried connecting just the converter and connecting the tx and rx wires of it together, and sending a message via serial monitor, i do get the same thing back

Comment: At the moment when the Arduino IDE program tells you "programming" you have to press the RESET button on the arduino board to start the actual program phase. Try that and probably you will manage to upload it. Then, if you want to automate this, you will need a serial converter with the DTR pin (and wire this to the reset pin through a capacitor)

Comment: i press the reset button while the sketch is compiling and let go when uploading starts, that is when i get the error above given

Comment: You just have to press momentarily and then let it go immediately when the IDE says "programming".. You don't have to rush because you should have a couple of seconds. But then... Are you sure the USB port stopped working and not the microcontroller?

Comment: the arduino does turn on and also runs the previous installed sketch , only reasons that make me believe everything else is fine

Comment: Well, if the bootloader gets screwed up maybe not... But I don't think so... Just for reference.. Did you try to swap the RX and TX cables?

Comment: yes i tried many times

Comment: If you have a multimeter or (better) an oscilloscope try looking at the signals on the pins TX and RX. Try using another arduino, try desoldering the resistors between the onboard FT232 and the ATmega328P chip, and... Well, without having the board here I can't give you any further advice..